# Handling permission using metadata

Tags: permissions, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, metadata

I'm working for a company with several departments (human resources, comptability, and such).

Each department must be able to create documents.

User groups must be able to access documents from a given set of departments.

Metadata is the only way I can use to display documents the way the company wants (each department has one tag). Is there a way to implement permissions the way I describe while using metadata tags ?

Answer (score 3):

I would continue to use metadata tags but use actual SharePoint groups to limit the permissions. Give each department their own document library where the respective group contribute permissions and other departments have read permissions as necessary.

Then you can use a content query web part to roll up the documents and not have to worry about permissions as it will be handled automatically by the server for you.

Comment: Sounds like a plan. I've ran into an issue though: I can't seem to find a way to filter by metadata tags using the Content Query Web Part. My column "Departments" of type "Managed Metadata" isn't available as a filterable column.

Comment: After getting more documentation on the subject, it appears that the "Managed Metadata" columns sometimes do not appear when they allow multiple values. But my Managed Metadata column doesn't allow multiple values, so that's not the reason why it doesn't show.